# Why does `Rprof` list out `match.fun` actual function instead of its alias

Tags: r

`Rprof` list out `match.fun` actual function instead of its alias (here `func`)

```
loopMillion <- function() { for(i in 1:1e6) {cat("")}}
loopHalfMillion <- function() { for(i in 1:5e5) {cat("")}}
Rprof()
for(func_str in c("loopMillion", "loopHalfMillion")) {
 func <- match.fun(func_str);
 func()  
}
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()

*Output*
$by.self
         self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"cat"         2.12    57.61       2.48     67.39
"func"        1.20    32.61       3.68    100.00
"stdout"      0.36     9.78       0.36      9.78

$by.total
         total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"func"         3.68    100.00      1.20    32.61
"cat"          2.48     67.39      2.12    57.61
"stdout"       0.36      9.78      0.36     9.78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything surprising here. You copy the functions and bind that copy to the `func` symbol. Only this copy is called and never the original functions. Thus, calls to the original functions are not seen by `Rprof`.

Maybe you want this:

```
loopMillion <- function() { for(i in 1:1e6) {cat("")}}
loopHalfMillion <- function() { for(i in 1:5e5) {cat("")}}
Rprof()
for(func_str in c("loopMillion", "loopHalfMillion")) {
  do.call(func_str, list())
}
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()
#$by.self
#                  self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
#"cat"                 13.26    87.24      13.94     91.71
#"loopMillion"          0.86     5.66      10.14     66.71
#"stdout"               0.68     4.47       0.68      4.47
#"loopHalfMillion"      0.40     2.63       5.06     33.29
```